# adding rolling mean column to multi-index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a multi-index with stock names and then stock data.  It has 65 different stocks and the dates go on for 5 years- so the partial DF looks like this

```
                            High    Low Open    Px_last    Volume
                   Date         
SPOM US equity  12/31/2012  0.4575  0.2925  0.4575  0.3975  8890
                 1/1/2013   0.4575  0.2925  0.4575  0.3975  8890
                 1/2/2013   0.3975  0.3225  0.3975  0.3225  3400
                 1/3/2013   0.3738  0.28    0.34    0.29    48933
                 1/4/2013   0.4     0.3175  0.36    0.3175  3610
                 1/7/2013   0.47    0.2863  0.3      0.46   61854
                 1/8/2013   0.54    0.39    0.48    0.4575  86644
```

I want to add a columns with 10D rolling average and I looked at some other posts such as this one  stackoverflow.com/questions/38334832/rolling-averages-on-groups.  I used this code and it did not throw any errors but the issue is the 10D-MA columns shows the entire dataframe with nan.  It doesn't calculate any numbers.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and why this is not producing the desired results

```
df2['10D-MA'] = df2.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df2: df2['Px_last'].rolling(10).mean())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['10D']=df.groupby(level=0).Px_last.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(10,min_periods=1).mean())
df
Out[93]: 
                     High     Low    Open  Px_last  Volume       10D
       Date                                                         
equity 12/31/2012  0.4575  0.2925  0.4575   0.3975    8890  0.397500
       1/1/2013    0.4575  0.2925  0.4575   0.3975    8890  0.397500
       1/2/2013    0.3975  0.3225  0.3975   0.3225    3400  0.372500
       1/3/2013    0.3738  0.2800  0.3400   0.2900   48933  0.351875
       1/4/2013    0.4000  0.3175  0.3600   0.3175    3610  0.345000
       1/7/2013    0.4700  0.2863  0.3000   0.4600   61854  0.364167
       1/8/2013    0.5400  0.3900  0.4800   0.4575   86644  0.377500
```

Comment: @JWestwood Yw~ happy coding